# .netcore 2.2 Session variable problem when calling page from iframe

Tags: .net, session, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.2

we are able to run session variable when we directly login from its local address. but we are not able to set or get the variables from session while we are calliing from an iframe here is our startup.cs

```
services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
      {
          // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
          options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => false;
          options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
      });

      ////////////////

      services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("MyPolicy", builder =>
      {
          builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                 .AllowAnyMethod()
                 .AllowAnyHeader()
                 .AllowCredentials()
                 ;
      }));

      services.AddMemoryCache();
      services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2)
          .AddJsonOptions(options =>
          {
              options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver
                  = new Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver();
          })
          .AddSessionStateTempDataProvider()
          .AddRazorPagesOptions(o =>
          {
              o.Conventions.ConfigureFilter(new IgnoreAntiforgeryTokenAttribute());
          });
      ;

      services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
      services.AddSession(options =>
      {
          options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;

      });


      services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
```

with this settings. we are able run our site very well but when we call it from iframe from another domain. we are able to acces site but its not able to write session variables.

Need Help!!

Answer (score 0):

here is the correct answer

config the Session option like

```
services.AddSession(options =>
    {
        options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
        options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.None;
        options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
    });
```

now it works

and config the Authentication part

```
services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddCookie(options =>
      {
          options.LoginPath = new PathString("/login");
          options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
          options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.None;
      });
```